# How to wrap conduit pipe into state?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, conduit

I have a code that takes stream of json arrays from stdin and computes [candlesticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart) from them. I've implemented function `diff` that should compute difference between old state and new state in `State` Monad, but I don't know how to use with conduit. The idea is that each json array is a batch of data. For each batch we compute new state of `candlesticks` and `diff` between old state and new state and print `diff`.

AFAIK I should wrap conduit inside `StateT` somehow, but monad transformers are still new to me and it's not obvious to me how to do that.

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Ord
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as Map
import GHC.Exts (groupWith)
import qualified Data.Conduit.Combinators as CC
import Data.Conduit (await, yield, (.|))
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC hiding (last, head, maximum, minimum, map)
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import Data.JsonStream.Parser hiding ((.|))
import System.IO (stdin, stdout)
import Control.Lens


jsonParseValue :: Parser a -> Conduit BC.ByteString IO a
jsonParseValue parser = doParse $ runParser parser
    where
        doParse :: ParseOutput a -> Conduit BC.ByteString IO a
        doParse out = case out of
                        ParseYield value newOutput  -> do
                            yield value
                            doParse newOutput
                        ParseNeedData cont ->
                            awaitForever $ doParse . cont
                        ParseDone remaining -> return ()
                        ParseFailed err -> error err

first (_, _, x, _, _, _) = x
second (_, _, _, x, _, _) = x
third (_, _, _, _, x, _) = x
fourth (_, _, _, _, _, x) = x

group' :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [(b, [a])]
group' k vs = map (\g -> (k $ head g, g)) $ groupWith k vs

candle :: (Num a, Ord a) => V.Vector (Int, Int, a, a, a, a) -> (a, a, a, a)
candle vs = (V.maximum $ V.map first vs, V.minimum $ V.map second vs, third $ V.head vs, fourth $ V.last vs)

candles :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(Int, Int, a, a, a, a)] -> Map.Map Int (Map.Map Int (a, a, a, a))
candles vs = Map.fromList $ Prelude.map (\(k, g) ->  (k, Map.fromList $ Prelude.map (\(t, gt) -> (t, candle $ V.fromList gt)) $ group' (\(_, x, _, _, _, _) -> x) g)) $ group' (\(x, _, _, _, _, _) -> x) vs

update :: (Ord a) => Map.Map Int (Map.Map Int (a, a, a, a)) -> Map.Map Int (Map.Map Int (a, a, a, a)) -> Map.Map Int (Map.Map Int (a, a, a, a))
update new old = Map.unionWith (Map.unionWith (\(mm1, mn1, o1, c1) (mm2, mn2, o2, c2) -> (max mm1 mm2, min mn1 mn2, o1, max c1 c2))) old new

diff' old new = Map.differenceWith (\ n o -> Just (Map.differenceWith (\ x y -> Just x) n o)) new old

diff cs return Map.empty :: State (Map.Map Int (Map.Map Int (a, a, a, a))) (Map.Map Int (Map.Map Int (a, a, a, a)))
printCandles = forever $ do
    l <- liftIO $ BC.getLine
    let cs = candles $ parseByteString candlesParser l
    old <- get
    let new = update cs old
    put new
    let d = diff new old
    liftIO $ if Map.null d then return () else BL.putStrLn $ encode d

main = runStateT printCandles Map.empty
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you're trying to tie the state in with the code above, but I think the function you're looking for is [`runStateC`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.4/conduit-1.2.13/Data-Conduit-Lift.html#v:runStateC).

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Thanks for your comment. I've actually tried that but failed. See my updated question. For now I've done this without conduit with forever reading stdin line by line. Can you show how to achieve what I initially wanted with conduit given that I showed the code without conduit now? I mean it should be clear now what I want.

Comment: The code above has syntax errors, missing imports, and missing identifiers. It's also significantly larger than a minimal case to identify what you're trying to solve. I'd recommend working this down to a minimal repro that runs on its own.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Here is full code https://github.com/purpleP/candlesticks/blob/master/app/Main.hs But I thought that idea is clear. Parse data from stdin, make candlesticks from it, merge current candlesticks with candlesticks from data obtaining new candlesticks that would be current state on the next iteration. Other details are unimportant. The question is how to use State monad (candlesticks are state) inside `Conduit`. Will fixup question later, because I'm writing from the phone.

Comment: As a note to my future self, or anyone else getting here via Google: what I needed to discover was [Data.Conduit.Lift](https://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2014/01/conduit-transformer-exception).